# aplay error in Intel edison

Tags: alsa, intel-edison

I am using the following command to test sound on Intel Edison.

```
root@12345:/# aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

But I am getting this error message.

```
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:1697:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:1:29:Unexpected char
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3417:(config_file_open) /home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3339:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3788:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
aplay: main:730: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the device using

```
# aplay -D hw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Also you can refer to the [official Audio Setup guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjE39yg4s_MAhVP0mMKHS_jBF4QFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.intel.com%2Fsupport%2Fedison%2Fsb%2Fedisonaudio_332434001.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFDSbGnTPIWmy2aA6zJvJRaki5zdQ&sig2=TWbSLrR0zg7n6jzlCg0s7g&bvm=bv.121421273,d.cGc).